# How to connect ionic app with sql server via web api

Tags: ionic2

I want to connect app that is made using ionic framework with SQL server via web API. Already I have a database in SQL server and I have created web application using it.It also used web API. Now I want to create mobile app for it using ionic framework

Comment: did you  take this https://blog.ionicframework.com/10-minutes-with-ionic-2-calling-an-api/ and other one https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-connect-database-sql-server-in-ionic/54881

Comment: Thanks for your help.I'll refer.

Comment: I referred  above two articles.But it's not enough to understand.Could you please give me another solution.It's difficult to find out articles for my problem.

Comment: Im used for a SQLite, and firebase its very easy to handle , https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sqlite/ fire base https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/build-a-real-time-hybrid-app-with-ionic-firebase

Comment: I can not use other web server.because of I already have create database in SQL server and also I have a web application.So what I want is to create mobile application for my already created web application.To do that I want some examples for understand how to link web API and ionic app